# Here Maps for Javascript: Disabling WHEEL_ZOOM doesn't make page scrollable

Tags: here-api

we implemented HERE maps in the design of our pages, so that it takes up the full width of the browser window. We also are using marker clustering and info bubbles that open on tap events.

See screenshot.

[Here Maps Fullwidth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7pKc.jpg)

I would like to disable the mouse scroll to affect the zoom and pan of the map yet retain the ability to scroll to the bottom of the page. It seems that disabling the wheelzoom like this disables the window scroll behavior completely (as the map is full width). 
Are there any alternative suggestions/ tips on what to try?

```
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
// disable wheel zoom behavior
behavior.disable(H.mapevents.Behavior.WHEELZOOM)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to achieve this right now. If you disable wheelzoom, API doesn't propagate the event. The team is aware of this behavior and will deliver an update in the near future.

FYI, the correct way to disable the Behavior's feature looks like this:
`behavior.disable(H.mapevents.Behavior.Feature.WHEEL_ZOOM);`

See [Behavior#disable](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.mapevents.Behavior.html#disable) documentation for more details.